# How can I initialize all environment variables in OSX?

Tags: osx, gui-emacs

If I start GUI emacs in OSX (not from the terminal) it does not know about my user environment variables.

The `exec-path-from-shell` [package mostly solves this](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell), but while you can explicitly initialize specific environment variables, I can't see a way to initialize *all* environment variables.

I use environment variables to supply secrets to my applications, so I tend to have a lot of them and would prefer not to have to add and remove them from my `init.el`.

Comment: Which shell are you using?  Most shells have a command to list the set variables, e.g. in `bash` it is `set`

Comment: @AndrewSwann I'm using zsh.

Comment: `set` in `zsh`, without any argument, also just produces a list of variables

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I could come up with:

```
(defun source-file-and-get-envs (filename)
  (let* ((cmd (concat ". " filename "; env"))
         (env-str (shell-command-to-string cmd))
         (env-lines (split-string env-str "\n"))
         (envs (mapcar (lambda (s) (replace-regexp-in-string "=.*$" "" s)) env-lines)))
    (delete "" envs)))

(exec-path-from-shell-copy-envs (source-file-and-get-envs "~/.profile")))
```

It sources the given file, then gets just the environment variable names from `env`.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see a way to initialize all environment variables.

```
(let ((bim (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bashrc; echo -n $BIM")))
  (setenv "BIM" bim))
```

Something like this should do the trick. You'll probably want to add a loop.

Comment: This looks like I'd still need to list out all of the environment variables I want. I have roughly 50 custom variables set, and want to use _all_ of them without having to name each one.

Comment: The command `env` will list out all environment variables and their values.